# Insert value corresponding to foreign key in View (executing the application)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, foreign-key-relationship

I'm a beginner in Rails. While I'm reading the documentation and tutorials I am porting a simple application I have in production in another language (Java generated with GeneXus)

I'm building an employee shift tracker, so I have two tables: users and shifts, with these associations

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shifts
end

class Shift < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I also added the corresponding user_id in the shift model when creating the SQLite database.

My problem is that, when trying to insert a new record via the New view, the "user_id" field doesn't validate correctly any valid user_id number I try to write. What I'm I supposed to insert in this field? (In my current running application in java this field would accept the user_id value )

When tryng to insert any value inside the "user" field in the "shifts" view, I get the following error

> User(#63152640) expected, got
>   String(#19315740)

---

---

Here's the View source

new.html.erb

```
<h1>New shift</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', shifts_path %>
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@shift) do |f| %>
  <% if @shift.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@shift.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this shift from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @shift.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :start %><br />
    <%= f.datetime_select :start %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :end %><br />
    <%= f.datetime_select :end %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :status %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :status %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :user %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :user %> //<-- What should I write here? User_id?
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

---

(All of this was generated with scaffolding)
Also, the new action in the shifts_controller is

```
def new
 @shift = Shift.new
end
```

Comment: will do as soon as I get home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out.

Turns out the view generated with scaffolding, in the user field was like this:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :user %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :user %> //<-- What should I write here? User_id?
  </div>
```

I changed `:user` for `:user_id` and it worked. I tested writing 1 in the user_id field and it saved correctly.

Then in the **index.html.erb**,  I changed `shift.user` in the list for `shift.user.username` and now the list shows me which shift belongs to which user correctly

Answer (score 0):

According to your question your tables are named user and shift. That is not standard rails naming convention. All table names should be in plural so users and shifts. You can go around this if you have to but I would not recommend it.

However, if you really want to keep those table names then you can specify that with set_table_name like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name 'user'
  has_many :shifts
end

class Shift < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name 'shift'
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Edit:

If you want to have a better way to control which user the shift is for, then to manually enter the id, you can use the select helper in your views. Perhaps like this:

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :user_id %><br />
    <%= f.select :user_id, options_from_collection_for_select(User.all, :id, :name) %>
  </div>
```

The key is to use the options_from_collection_for_select helper. User.all loads all users and each user will be one option in the select. :id is the User attribute which will be the option value and :name is the User attribute that will be displayed in the select list. If you want to display another User attribute in the list, then all you need to do is change that.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm using the standard conventions so the tables names are really in plural (I'm writing this out of memory because I don't have access to my code right now). I'll update the question, but thanks for pointing this out

Comment: Okey. FYI, you edited the wrong things. Class names are in singular, table names are in plural. Also, I can't think of anything else that is wrong without more info so it would be good if you could supply the controller action where you try to create the objects and perhaps the views also.

Comment: I just realized I edited the wrong things. Corrected one more time :P checking the real source.

Comment: Glad it worked out. If you want a better solution than the text_field for user_id then you can check out my additional example

Comment: Excellent, thank you for the even better solution (which was what I was going to aim for at the end).